# C# Visual studio tools for office gives this error: Excel is running into problems with the X add-in

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I'm trying to run a sample in visual studio tools for office but when I try to run it Excel gives this error:

```
Excel is running into problems with the X add-in. If this keeps happening disable this add-in and check for available updates
```

My code is as below:

```
private void btnA2P_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range currentFind = null;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range firstFind = null;

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range AllWords = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.get_Range("A1", "B3");               

            currentFind = AllWords.Find("a", Type.Missing,
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart,
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext, false,
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

            while (currentFind != null)
            {
                currentFind.Replace(currentFind.Value, currentFind.Value.ToString().Replace("a", "b"));                 

                if (firstFind == null)
                {
                    firstFind = currentFind;
                }    

                else if (currentFind.get_Address(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1)
                      == firstFind.get_Address(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1))
                {
                    break;
                }

                currentFind.Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
                currentFind.Font.Bold = true;

                currentFind = AllWords.FindNext(currentFind);
            }
        }
```

Moreover when I want to debug the code it returns null from the Find method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method returns `null` if no match is found.

What line of code causes the issue with the plug-in? What plug-in are you talking about?